# Documentar con Swagger

Tags: swagger

Tengo que documentar lo siguiente ruta con Swagger:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora con la información que encontré solo pude lograr que se vea así :c
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay manera de que sea igual el post? :x

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Es preferible el código en formato texto y no las imagenes. En todo caso, lo que muestras no tiene nada que ver con Swagger, simplemente muestras cómo consumes un endpoint y lo que devuelve Swagger en su API. Saludos